# Why when saving an NSINteger to NSSNumber results in NSNumber having random weird result

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsnumber

item.itemId is in coredata as an NSNumber and itemModel.itemID is a NSInteger. 
When saving itemModel.itemId to the itemId in core data it prints out -31016 for item.ItemID and 100056 for the NSInteger.

The following two lines prints out -31016 100056.

```
item.itemId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:itemModel.itemId];
NSLog(@"%@ %ld",item.itemId,(long)itemModel.itemId);
```

ItemId is model i've created and itemId is declared like this.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger itemId
```

The value for itemID is set like this coming from the server as an integer.

```
self.itemId = [attributes[@"Id"] integerValue];
```

Comment: What should be `item.itemId`?

Comment: How do you declare 'item' and what does its NSObject file look?

Comment: what is the value of itemId?

Comment: I've updated the question. @Kreiri the value is coming from the server as 100056 and I'm saving that to itemModel.itemId. When I log it the value displayed is 100056. When I save it to nsnumber and log that it comes out as -31016.

Comment: -1 confusing question, lacking much detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Core Data attribute is problaby defined as `Integer 16`. In that case, all values
stored in the Core Data object are (silently) truncated to 16-bit. In your example:

```
100056 = 0x186D8
```

is truncated to

```
-31016 = 0x86D8
```

Changing the attribute to `Integer 32` or `Integer 64` should solve the problem.

Comment: So even though the OP says the type is `NSInteger`, it isn't really?

Comment: @trojanfoe: He has a local variable `NSInteger itemID`, and a managed object `item` which has a property `NSNumber itemID` corresponding to an entity attribute "Integer 16". Well, that's how I interpret the question ...

Comment: +1 This is certainly what is happening; however the question is very unclear.

Comment: spot on this was correct. Sorry for being unclear in my question.